# SQL Query for Item and Item set details

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two table the first one is product which is store product and product set master details here is the difference between product or product set master where issetofitem =1 here is product set master other wise single product and another table product set details which is foreign key of product which is the name **ItemSetMasterId**

Below the table structure please help for this

[image]

Comment: Can you describe properly?

Comment: give some some sample data also

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, this is a combination of `union all` and `inner join`

```
select Srno, ProductCode, PartName, PartNo, 
      (case when issetofitem = 0 then 'product' else 'product set master' end) productinfo 
from product p union all
select p.Srno, p.ProductCode, p.PartName, p.PartNo, 
      'product set details' as productinfo 
from product p
inner join ProductSet s on s.ProductId = p.ProductId;
```

Comment: Product set detail should be below the each product set master

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data, this would seem to do what you want:

```
select p.srno, p.productcode, p.partname, p.partno,
       (case when p.issetofitem = 1 then 'Product Set Master' else 'Product' end)
from product p
union all
select p.srno, p.productcode, p.partname, p.partno,
       'Product Set Details'
from product p join
     productset ps 
     on p.productid = ps.productid;
```

I feel like something is missing from the data -- this seems to be assuming that everything in `productdetails` is in a single set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it will work for you:

```
SELECT SrNo, ProductCode, PartName, PartNo, Detail FROM (
SELECT SrNo, ProductCode, PartName, PartNo,
    (CASE WHEN p.IsSetofitem = 1 THEN 'Product Set Master' ELSE 'Product' END) AS Detail,ProductId AS ParentId FROM Product 
UNION ALL
SELECT p.SrNo, p.ProductCode, p.PartName, p.PartNo,'Product Set Details' AS Detail, ps.ItemSetMasterId AS ParentId FROM Product p 
join ProductSet ps on p.ProductId = ps.ProductId
WHERE p.IsSetofitem = 1 ) 
ORDER BY ParentId
```